# Error: assertion failed in ItemFileWriteStore

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events, dojox.grid

I am using `dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore` as store for the grid.
    when I tried to add the data to store using `store.newItem()` method,
    I am getting the below error.

> " Error: assertion failed in ItemFileWriteStore ".

Can any one help me why I am getting this error?

Please find the code snippet:

```
   var tabledata={identifier:"TimeStamp",items:[]};
   var store=new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data:tabledata});

   var data=xhrpost();
   //data contains
// {"TimeStamp":"2011/12/07 04:37:29 ","UserName":" root ","Command":" ppm restart"}| //{"TimeStamp":"2011/12/07 05:02:14 ","UserName":" root ","Command":" ppm restart"}|
//{"TimeStamp":"2011/12/07 05:33:01 ","UserName":" root ","Command":" ppm restart"}|
//{"TimeStamp":"2011/12/07 06:18:17 ","UserName":" root ","Command":" ppm restart"}

    var arrdata=data.spilt("|");
   for(var i=0;i<arrdata.length;i++)
   {
   //i am getting ajax response as text so i am converting to json
   var row=dojo.fromJson(data[i]);
    store.newItem(row);
  }
```

Comment: `data.spilt` should be `data.split`, and in the for loop, you should do `fromJson(arrdata[i])`. Fix that and see if you still have a problem.